# Poor performance with Search container in Liferay 7

Tags: performance, liferay, liferay-dxp, searchcontainer

I'm facing performance issues while trying to show   data with Liferay Search-container.
I've 1000 record (Web content), I'm using pagination also. When refreshing page, performance are so poor.
Is there optimisation to do in Liferay to decrease laoding time?

Comment: There is clearly not enough context here to provide any reasonable answer.  You might be running Elastic on a 486 running an old version of linux and having only 1g of memory available. You might have 20k concurrent users doing search. You might have 2k concurrent Liferay users on your node that is using a single core i686 with 2g of memory. Any one answer we would give here might not touch on what your true problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to figure out where you loose the performance. If you fetch 1000 objects from database, and - before showing them - fetch additional information for these 1000 objects in 1000 independent queries: That's what you'll need to optimize. If you fetch 100000 objects from the database only to throw away 99000 before showing 10 of the remaining 1000 objects on a page: There's your problem.

As you mention Web Content: If the article is fully fetched from the database, it might be parsed to separate the individual languages contained in an article, and that takes time. Articles will end up in a cache, and you can check the cache size: If you have a cache size of 900 objects, you'll constantly overflow the cache and never reuse a previously parsed article.

In other words: You're talking about performance tuning. Step one in performance tuning is: Measure, and figure out what eats up your performance in the first place. Identify, fix, rinse, repeat. There's no magic wand or switch.

Comment: It&#39;s about kaleo workflow engine. Retriving articles is really smooth, but updating workflow status for every journal content is the issue